# Nav item inside ul with a dropdown button not showing scroll bar for the horizontal li elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a ul inside which I have a `li` which is a nav-item. In that `nav-item`, I have a more options button which is a `dropdown`. I was facing an issue that the dropdown menu items were hiding behind the below `div`. So to make it visible I made the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` property of the `ul` element as visible. After this fix, the dropdown menu started showing above the `div`. But now I am facing an issue that when there are too many `nav` items it is overflowing in the `UI` and I am not getting a horizontal `scrollbar` as I used to get earlier. Can someone provide me a fix for this issue in order to cater to both my needs, ie. show the dropdown elements on top of the below div and show horizontal scrollbar when the nav-items in the ul overflow. Thanks in advance for any help!

```css
#dropdown_id.dropdown-menu.show {
  /*display: contents !important;*/
  /* z-index: 2000 !important; */
  opacity: 1;
  float: left !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
  margin-left: -87px;
  min-width: 175px !important;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.dropdown_class.dropdown-toggle::after {
  /*display: contents !important;*/
  /* z-index: 2000 !important; */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-linetriangle no-hover-bg sub-tabs mb-1 div_for_tab_app" style="overflow-x: visible;overflow-y: visible;">
    {% if data.other_proposal_model_data.is_room == True %}
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link design_ids" id="all" data-id="all" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="designContent1" href="#designContent1" aria-expanded="true">Summary</a>
    </li>
    {% else %}
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active design_ids active" id="all" data-id="all" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="designContent1" href="#designContent1" aria-expanded="true">Summary</a>
    </li>
    {% endif %}
    <!-- {% if is_uploaded is True %}

                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link design_ids upload-bom-tab" data-id="export" data-toggle="tab"
                  aria-controls="designContent2" aria-expanded="true" tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo"
                  style="max-width:200px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">Uploaded Data</a>
                </li>

              {% endif %} -->

    {% for proposal_item in data.new_design_model_instance %}
    <li class="nav-item tab_name_append">
      <a class="nav-link design_ids" id="tab_{{proposal_item.bom_id}}" data-id="{{proposal_item.bom_id}}" data-toggle="tab" aria-controls="designContent2" aria-expanded="true" tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="{{proposal_item.name}}" style="max-width:175px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;"><span style="max-width:0.4px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;">{{proposal_item.name}}</span>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="template-dropdown-btn dropdown-toggle action-btn dropdown_class" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
          <i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v more_room_option" id="more_action_{{proposal_item.bom_id}}" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size:15px; position: absolute; margin-left: 74px; margin-top: -28px; color:#3070bb;" data-id="{{proposal_item.bom_id}}" aria-hidden="true"
            aria-hidden="true" tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="More Options">
                        </i>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown_id">
          <a class="dropdown-item edit_room" style="background-color: #f2efef;" data-id="{{proposal_item.bom_id}}" data-name="{{proposal_item.name}}" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i class="fas fa-edit" data-id="{{proposal_item.bom_id}}" aria-hidden="true" aria-hidden="true" tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="Edit name"></i> Edit Room Name
          </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item delete_room" style="background-color: #f2efef; z-index:999999 !important;" data-id="{{proposal_item.bom_id}}" href="javascript:void(0)">
            <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" data-id="{{proposal_item.bom_id}}" aria-hidden="true" aria-hidden="true" tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="Delete room"></i> Delete Room
          </a>
        </div>
      </a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
    <i href="javascript:void(0)" class="fa fa-plus" style="position: relative; top: 12px; font-size: 18px; padding-left: 10px;" data-toggle="modal" aria-hidden="true" tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="Add a new room" data-target="#newTemplate"></i>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content" id="tab1" style="margin-top: -10px;">

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane tab1_class active" id="designContent1" aria-expanded="true" aria-labelledby="all">
      <table id="example" class="table table-striped proposal-bom-table">
        <thead class="thead-light">
          <tr>
            <th>S.No</th>
            <th>Make & Model No.</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="This is retail price suggested by manufacturer">MSRP</th>
            <th style="display: none;" tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="This is your discount on MSRP">Discount</th>
            <th tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="This is Cost Price after discount on MSRP">Cost Price</th>
            {% if data.other_proposal_model_data.is_markup == False %}
            <th tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="This is your margin on Cost Price">Margin</th>
            {% else %}
            <th tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="This is your markup on Cost Price">Markup</th>
            {% endif %}
            <th tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="This is your Selling Price to Client for 1 unit">Selling Price</th>
            {% if data.other_proposal_model_data.equipment_discount_per_line_item is True %}
            <th tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="This is the Equipment Discount on your Selling Price">Equipment Discount</th>
            {% else %}
            <th class="d-none" tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="This is the Equipment Discount on your Selling Price">Equipment Discount</th>
            {% endif %} {% if data.ricoh_flag == True or data.proposal.labour_on_total_check == True %}
            <th class="bom-labor-item d-none" style="width:55px;" tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="This is labor amount on 1 unit including design and engineering">{{data.proposal.labor_tax_name_col}}</th>
            {% else %}
            <th class="bom-labor-item" style="width:55px;" tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="This is labor amount on 1 unit including design and engineering">{{data.proposal.labor_tax_name_col}}</th>
            {% endif %}
            <th tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="This is the final Selling Price for all units, including labor charges">
              Extended</th>
            <th style="display: none;">ID</th>
            <th style="display: none;">Proposal ID</th>
            <th style="display: none;">DESIGN ID</th>
            <th class="action-btn-wrapper">ACTION</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="table_body">
          {% for proposal_item in data.proposal_data %}
          <tr id="{{proposal_item.id}}" class="proposal_item_row" data-id="{{proposal_item.bom_id}}" data-product-id="{{proposal_item.product_id}}">
            <td><i class="fa fa-arrows-alt"> </i><b>{{forloop.counter}}</b></td>
            <td class="inform" tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="{{proposal_item.model_number}}">{{proposal_item.model_number}} </td>
            <td style="max-width:0.4px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;" tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="{{proposal_item.description}}">{{proposal_item.description}} </td>
            <td class="quantity_input" id="{{proposal_item.model_number}}" data-original-title="{{proposal_item.model_number}}">{{proposal_item.quantity}}</td>
            {% load humanize %}
            <td>{{data.proposal.type}}{{proposal_item.price|floatformat:"2"|intcomma}}</td>
            {% if proposal_item.dealer_price_check != True %}
            <td style="display: none;">{{proposal_item.discount|floatformat:"0"|intcomma}}%</td>
            {% else %}
            <td style="opacity: 0.4; display: none;" disabled>{{proposal_item.discount|floatformat:"0"|intcomma}}%</td>
            {% endif %}
            <td>{{data.proposal.type}}{{proposal_item.amount|floatformat:"2"|intcomma}}</td>
            <td>{{proposal_item.margin|floatformat:"0"|intcomma}}%</td>
            <td>{{data.proposal.type}}{{proposal_item.sell_price|floatformat:"2"|intcomma}}</td>
            {% if data.other_proposal_model_data.equipment_discount_per_line_item is True %}
            <td>{{proposal_item.equipment_discount}}%</td>
            {% else %}
            <td class="d-none">{{proposal_item.equipment_discount}}%</td>
            {% endif %} {% if data.ricoh_flag == True or data.proposal.labour_on_total_check == True %} {% if data.proposal.labour_unit is True %}
            <td class="bom-labor-item d-none">{{data.proposal.type}}{{proposal_item.labour|floatformat:"2"|intcomma}}</td>
            {% else %}
            <td class="bom-labor-item d-none">{{proposal_item.labour|floatformat:"0"|intcomma}}%</td>
            {% endif %} {% else %} {% if data.proposal.labour_unit is True %}
            <td class="bom-labor-item">{{data.proposal.type}}{{proposal_item.labour|floatformat:"2"|intcomma}}</td>
            {% else %}
            <td class="bom-labor-item">{{proposal_item.labour|floatformat:"0"|intcomma}}%</td>
            {% endif %} {% endif %}
            <td>{{data.proposal.type}}{{proposal_item.labour_extended|floatformat:"2"|intcomma}}</td>
            <td style="display: none;" data-id="{{proposal_item.dealer_price_check}}">{{proposal_item.id}}</td>
            <td style="display: none;">{{proposal_item.proposal_id}}</td>
            <td style="display: none;">{{proposal_item.bom_id}}</td>
            <td class="action-btn-wrapper">
              <div class="action-btn"><i class="ft-edit" aria-hidden="true" tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="Edit"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="ft-trash-2" aria-hidden="true" aria-hidden="true" tool-tip-toggle="tooltip-demo" data-original-title="Delete"></i></div>
            </td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Without code it will be difficult for anyone to answer and these question will be closed without getting answers, so share what you have done to help better.(I am not the one downvoted!)

Comment: Please add code snippet so the community can help you better

Comment: Added the code snippet